# Run SQL multiple times using input value from a sheet and generate graphs accordingly

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am quite new to Excel VBA. I have to automate a report in Excel which plots Teradata System CPU graphs. I have been successful in connecting to Teradata database and run the SQL to plot the graph for one day based on a value given in a separate sheet as input.

What I need to do next is, to generate graph for different dates. The user should enter the start date and end date on one of the sheets and then the code for CPU usage should run separately for each date and then generate graph for each date accordingly. Can you kindly assist me on how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance

```vb
Public Sub GenerateGraph()

Dim i As Integer
Dim strConn As String
Dim Initials As String
' Create the Connection object
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Initials = "Initials"

systm = Application.VLookup(Worksheets(Initials).range("C2"), Worksheets(Initials).range("Y2:Z3"), 2, False)
UID = Application.VLookup(Worksheets(Initials).range("C2"), Worksheets(Initials).range("Y2:AA3"), 3, False)
pswd = Application.VLookup(Worksheets(Initials).range("C2"), Worksheets(Initials).range("Y2:AB3"), 4, False)
strConn = "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;DRIVER={Teradata};DBCName=" & systm & ";User ID=" & UID & ";Password=" & pswd & ";"


 con.ConnectionString = strConn
 con.Provider = "Teradata"
 con.Open strConn

strSQL = "sel username, SUM(ampcputime+parsercputime)"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM pdcrdata.dbqlogtbl_hst"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM firststeptime) IN       ( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' ) "
strSQL = strSQL & " AND LOGDATE=date-" & Sheets("Value").range("C5") & ""
strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY 1"
strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY 2 DESC;"

i = 2
Set rsResult = con.Execute(strSQL)
'Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C1000").Clear
Sheets("Slide1").range("A1:C1000").Value = ""
Sheets("Slide1").Cells(1, 1).Value = rsResult.Fields(0).Name
Sheets("Slide1").Cells(1, 2).Value = rsResult.Fields(1).Name
Sheets("Slide1").range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsResult

rsResult.Close
Set rsResult = Nothing



Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to have an incoming **date** type parameter. Change the `LOGDATE=date...` statement to use the incoming parameter rather than picking the date from a cell. You can then have a wrapper UDF that calls this UDF. Wrapper UDF will decide which dates to pass to this UDF

Comment: So if a user enters an entire year range, you want 365 daily graphs generated? On one worksheet? Also, where is the graph generated in that posted subroutine code?

Comment: @parfait well actually i am looking for the solution to my orignal question which is how to take start date and end date from a separate sheet and execute the above sql for those dates separately. 
Once the code is run for those dates, data can be copied into separate sheets and charts can be made accordingly. The original report requires dates for previous seven working days only. It would be great if someone can provide the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply run a parameterized query using [ADO Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/command-object-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) with your two dates as parameters. Adjust *mySheet* and *myRange* in param values:

```vb
con.ConnectionString = strConn
con.Provider = "Teradata"
con.Open strConn

' PREPARED STATEMENT (WITH QMARKS BUT NO DATA)
strSQL = "SELECT username, SUM(ampcputime+parsercputime)"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM pdcrdata.dbqlogtbl_hst"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM firststeptime)"
strSQL = strSQL & "         IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' )"
strSQL = strSQL & " AND LOGDATE BETWEEN CAST(? AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')"
strSQL = strSQL & "                 AND CAST(? AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')"
strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY 1"
strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY 2 DESC;"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
   .ActiveConnection = con
   .CommandText = strSQL
   .CommandType = adCmdText

   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("start_date", adVarchar, adParamInput, , Format(Sheets("mySheet").Range("myRange"), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("end_date", adVarchar, adParamInput, , Format(Sheets("mySheet").Range("myRange"), "YYYY-MM-DD"))

   Set rst = .Execute
End With
```